# Socket IO and MongoDB server

Tags: ios, node.js, mongodb, sockets, ubuntu

Today i installed MongoDB and Socket IO + Nodejs on Ubuntu (15.10)

Everything is installed correctly, but my server.js (making a realtime chat) does not make any connection, This is the script i have:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient, client = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;

client.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('Someone has connected!');
});
```

Just nothing happends:

[image]

Can anyone help me? THanks alot!

From a tutorial i had to add

```
<Script src="http://127.0.0.1/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

But it says it cant find it altho its installed.

my Index:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the port number is 8080? It is HTTP protocol port number. mongoDB port number is 27017

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure socket.io is installed

   ```
   npm install socket.io
   ```
2. As your server is not setup static files you should change the script src in your html to:

   ```
   <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: Ok if you haven't downloaded the Socket.io.js to your machine then change src to https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js instead of 127.0.0.1/socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: Well i did what you said, its spamming me in errors now; GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LAEsVNs 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Ok we are getting a little confused here. For socket.io, as you are going to be the client (e.g. the person who accesses the site) and the server, you need to make sure you have both the client and server versions of socket.io  available. When you add an item to your dependencies (and install by running npm install) you install a server side dependency. Your client will also need there own bit of code to talk to the server. This is your server code and in our case it will be the file cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js.

Comment: aah u changed ur solution, i did what u said, change to 3000, i cant access it with 127.0.0.1:3000/chatapp/   < on my HOST machine, when i do this on my UBUNTU Virtual machine i get: Cannot GET /chatapp/

Comment: To install the server side socket.io, in addition to adding the socket.io to your package.json you must then type the command npm install to install all of your dependencies (and subsequently socket.io) on your server.

Comment: Allright the npm install fixed it! I went on my website and it gave me errors about the dirname what u told me about, i use res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.php'); It says: cannot GET /chatapp (from socket.io website tutorial)

Comment: Is that because the files is in /var/www/html/chatapp/ ?